moveit2: detect when MoveItSimpleControllerManager is ready
On launching of my ROS2 system, one of the nodes very quickly makes a call to moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::move(), which is failing because the controller Action Server has not come up yet (see logs below). Is there a way to check MoveItSimpleControllerManager to know that all its controllers are up? If not, what's the preferred way to wait for the robot hardware to be "ready"? I could directly check each controller's Action Server, but that's a leaky abstraction (the intent is really checking whether the move_group is ready to execute a trajectory).
Relevant logs:
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.004490702] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group.move_action]: MoveGroupMoveAction: Received request
[bt_executor-11] [INFO] [1730849407.004604276] [planning_scene_interface_139278883613568.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group_interface]: Plan and Execute request accepted
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.004679770] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group.move_action]: executing..
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.004804973] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group.move_action]: Combined planning and execution request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning and execution pipeline.
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.004931716] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.005077752] [move_group]: Calling PlanningRequestAdapter 'ResolveConstraintFrames'
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.005108170] [move_group]: Calling PlanningRequestAdapter 'ValidateWorkspaceBounds'
[move_group-7] [WARN] [1730849407.005116899] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.validate_workspace_bounds]: It looks like the planning volume was not specified. Using default values.
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.005137713] [move_group]: Calling PlanningRequestAdapter 'CheckStartStateBounds'
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.005167511] [move_group]: Calling PlanningRequestAdapter 'CheckStartStateCollision'
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.005788751] [move_group.moveit.moveit.planners.ompl.model_based_planning_context]: Planner configuration 'tcp_curved_manipulator' will use planner 'geometric::RRTConnect'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.005912842] [move_group]: Calling Planner 'OMPL'
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.009882900] [move_group]: Calling PlanningResponseAdapter 'AddTimeOptimalParameterization'
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.013896998] [move_group]: Calling PlanningResponseAdapter 'ValidateSolution'
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.015302440] [move_group]: Calling PlanningResponseAdapter 'DisplayMotionPath'
[move_group-7] [WARN] [1730849407.015412422] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_pipeline]: The planner plugin did not fill out the 'planner_id' field of the MotionPlanResponse. Setting it to the planner ID name of the MotionPlanRequest assuming that the planner plugin does warn you if it does not use the requested planner.
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.015557949] [move_group.moveit.moveit.plugins.simple_controller_manager]: Returned 4 controllers in list
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.015571739] [move_group.moveit.moveit.plugins.simple_controller_manager]: Returned 4 controllers in list
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.015642744] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Validating trajectory with allowed_start_tolerance 0.01
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.015733011] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Starting trajectory execution ...
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.015793879] [move_group.moveit.moveit.plugins.simple_controller_manager]: Returned 4 controllers in list
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.015833104] [move_group.moveit.moveit.plugins.simple_controller_manager]: Returned 4 controllers in list
[move_group-7] [ERROR] [1730849407.015963895] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Action client not connected to action server: joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
[move_group-7] [ERROR] [1730849407.016034845] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Failed to send trajectory part 1 of 1 to controller joint_trajectory_controller
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.016055987] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Completed trajectory execution with status ABORTED ...
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1730849407.025999635] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group.move_action]: CONTROL_FAILED
[bt_executor-11] [INFO] [1730849407.026844745] [planning_scene_interface_139278883613568.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group_interface]: Plan and Execute request aborted
[bt_executor-11] [ERROR] [1730849407.027267883] [planning_scene_interface_139278883613568.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group_interface]: MoveGroupInterface::move() failed or timeout reached

